# Annoying overlay add

Tags: ads, overlay

This specific add keeps popping up as overlay at random.
It's always the same Facebook Maket thing.
I'd appreciate any hint on how to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: While that ad on screen, run `adb shell dumpsys window | grep mFocused` on PC. You will get the app showing that ad. Uninstall it. Report it. Blacklist it. Or whatever else you find appropriate.

Comment: @IrfanLatif `mFocusedWindow=Window{ffea4e u0 com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.orca.auth.StartScreenActivity}
    mFocusedApp=Token{a6af053 ActivityRecord{5bb9e8d u0 com.facebook.orca/.auth.StartScreenActivity t13163}}
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{7f3cd90 token=Token{a6af053 ActivityRecord{5bb9e8d u0 com.facebook.orca/.auth.StartScreenActivity t13163}}}`

Comment: Hello ElmoVanKielmo. Let me know if the answers to the duplicate questions do not work for you. I hope they do and solve the issue. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Firelord - I'll check.

Comment: Yes, the issue is resolved @Firelord - it turns out it was enough to revoke unnecessary permission to show alert popup on top of other apps. And it can be done via native app manager on my Android phone as it simply lists apps with this permission enabled.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Good to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, see @Ifran Latif's comment. This is a good action for finding malicious apps.

If it's simply an ad that you want to not see anymore, there are several ad blocker apps available that can help:

[AdAway](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.adaway/)

[AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/android-about)

[AdGuard](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-android/overview.html)

Comment: So far I can say that your answer is useful, yet adb didn't show the offending app - like the overlay ad was really smart. I'm checking ad blockers provided.